# Is there any possiblity in JPA to react to child objects being lazy loaded?

Tags: java, jpa, lazy-loading, eclipselink

I know about @PostLoad, but that has to be added to the lazily loaded child object. Is there any annotation or hook method that will lead to a method in the parent's context to be called after a child has been lazily loaded?
The problem I'm facing is that the child does not know the parent but I need to pass down some data known to the parent to every child after it has been loaded without loosing the lazy loading.
If not in vanilla JPA, might such an option exist in Eclipselink?

Comment: This is transient state that seems very specific to the parent->child relationship. What do you want to happen with that state when child is loaded without its parent, or from some other relationship? That said, I'd do it yourself in the object model by instrumenting the parent.getChild() call so that you update the child instance with the parent data before returning it. It will work the same regardless of the child being eager or lazy loaded

Comment: If a child was loaded alone, the state would be set by the code loading it - and propagated to its children. Instrumenting the getter might work, I'll try that; thank you for the idea.